# R repeat function until result met and can obtain number of iterations it took to achieve result

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, while-loop, markov-chains

MY following function denotes n as days and initial value x1. I'm trying to find the number of days it takes from any value or `rmicro<30` to reach `rmicro>=40`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `while` instead of `for`:

```
i = 2
while(si[i - 1] < 40){
  si[i]=si[i-1]+rpois(1,0.978+0.2*si[i-1]*exp(-0.03*si[i-1]))-rbinom(n,si[i- 1],0.1)
  i = i + 1
}

print(paste0('Iterations until 40: ', i - 1))
print(paste0('First value >= 40 ', si[i - 1]))
```

Comment: Hi sorry i tried your code but it doesn't work... what is i++?

Comment: Try it out now. Didn't realize R doesn't accept `i++` as a substitute for `i = i + 1`

Comment: nope... still doesn't seem to work haha...

Comment: When saying something doesn't work, you need to explain what error you're getting or else no one on here can help you. If you've initialized `si[1]` and `n`, which I assumed you did based on your original post, this should work. Also, what is `n`? Do you really want to stop your loop if you reach `n` iterations and haven't received `40` as a result, like your original post entails?

Comment: Sorry... I get the response  `Error in si[i - 1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`   Also what do you mean by initialising?